# Defer and Promise in angularjs not working properly

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs

I have now problem with `defer promise` in angularjs.

Here is my code:

```
var defer = $q.defer();

    defer.promise
    //First Execution
    .then(function () {
        TestService.GetSchoolYear().then(function (results) {
            $scope.schoolYears = results.data;
            $scope.schoolYear = results.data[0].schlYearName;
        });
    })
    //Second Execution
    .then(function () {
        TestService.GetAffiliation().then(function (results) {
            $scope.affiliation = results.data;
            $scope.school = results.data[0].affiliation;
        });
    })
    //Third Execution
    .then(function () {
        TestService.GetDepartment().then(function (results) {
            $scope.departments = results.data;
            $scope.department = results.data[0].depName;
            $scope.depCode = results.data[0].depCode;
        });
    })
    //Fourth Execution
    .then(function () {
        TestService.GetYearLevel2($scope.depCode).then(function (results) {
            $scope.yearLevels2 = results.data;
            $scope.yearLevel2 = results.data[0].yearName;
        });
    });
    defer.resolve();
```

All the execution is in order. But the defer execute in different function not in order.

What's wrong with my code?is there any problem with it.

I got that reference here:
https://thinkster.io/egghead/promises/

Is I'm missing something with my code. All I want is to execute function in order because there is some data required in other function.

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since the various functions of `TestService` seem to return a promise, you don't even need a `$q.defer` here - in fact this would be a [deferred anti-pattern](https://github.com/petkaantonov/bluebird/wiki/Promise-anti-patterns#the-deferred-anti-pattern).

Just chain them together and `return` the result:

```
return TestService.GetSchoolYear()
    .then(function (results) {
       $scope.schoolYears = results.data;
       $scope.schoolYear = results.data[0].schlYearName;

       return TestService.GetAffiliation();
    })
    .then(function (results) {
       $scope.affiliation = results.data;
       $scope.school = results.data[0].affiliation;

       return TestService.GetDepartment();
    })
    .then(function (results) {
       $scope.departments = results.data;
       $scope.department = results.data[0].depName;
       $scope.depCode = results.data[0].depCode;

       return TestService.GetYearLevel2($scope.depCode);
    })
    .then(function (results) {
       $scope.yearLevels2 = results.data;
       $scope.yearLevel2 = results.data[0].yearName;
       return results;
    });
```

Comment: When should i use `Defer` when it is ok to chain it?

Comment: You only ever need to use `$q.defer ` when you are converting a non-promise async function to work with promises. If you already have a function that returns a promise, like `$http`, then just return it, or return the new promise created with `.then`

Comment: ah ok..thanks for that information..i will try it and if it solve i will mark it as answer.. thank you.

Answer (score 0):

You are not returning anything in your `then` handlers, so the promises created by the `then()` methods resolve immediately and move onto the next `then()` immediately.

You need to return a promise so that there is something to wait on:

```
.then(function () {
    // v--------  here
    return TestService.GetSchoolYear().then(function (results) {
        $scope.schoolYears = results.data;
        $scope.schoolYear = results.data[0].schlYearName;
    });
})
```

It should also be noted that there's no need to use `$q.defer()` here (there's almost never a reason to use `$q.defer()`.

You can just use `$q.when()`:

```
 $q.when()
 .then(function () {
     // ....
 })
```

Or better yet, just start off your promise chain with the first async call you are making:

```
TestService.GetSchoolYear().then(function (results) {
    $scope.schoolYears = results.data;
    $scope.schoolYear = results.data[0].schlYearName;
})
.then(function () {
    return TestService.GetAffiliation().then(function (results) {
        // ...
    });
})  // ...
```

Comment: so it means it will execute my function in order?

Answer (score 0):

For the promise chaining to work the `then` function should return something.

Try this:

```
defer.promise
    //First Execution
    .then(function () {
        return TestService.GetSchoolYear().then(function (results) {
                 $scope.schoolYears = results.data;
                 $scope.schoolYear = results.data[0].schlYearName;
                 return results;
        });
    })
    //Second Execution
    .then(function () {
        return TestService.GetAffiliation().then(function (results) {
            $scope.affiliation = results.data;
            $scope.school = results.data[0].affiliation;
            return results;
        });
    })
    //Third Execution
    .then(function () {
        return TestService.GetDepartment().then(function (results) {
                 $scope.departments = results.data;
                 $scope.department = results.data[0].depName;
                 $scope.depCode = results.data[0].depCode;
                 return result;
        });
    })
    //Fourth Execution
    .then(function () {
        return TestService.GetYearLevel2($scope.depCode).then(function (results) {
            $scope.yearLevels2 = results.data;
            $scope.yearLevel2 = results.data[0].yearName;
            return results;
        });
    });
    defer.resolve();
```